# Screen flashes several time during Boot (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu

Just installed Kubuntu. I have dual boot with Win10. The problem is that the screen flashes several times during Kubuntu boot. What should I do?
[Video](https://youtu.be/1r1ewgjDy4w).